# Finding $\gamma : I \to M$ such that $\gamma(I)=M \cap V$

Tags: real-analysis, curves

Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^2)$, $f(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2,y^2+z^2)$ and let $M:=f^{-1}(\{(1,4)\})$, $p=(1,0,2)\in M$.

So I tried sketching $M$ - and I got:

[image]

The question is:

> Choosing an neighbourhood $V\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ of $p$, find an open
>   intervall $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ and a $C^1$ curve such that $\gamma
> > (I)=M\cap V$.

Here's another sketch:

[image]

I tried finding the black curve by using:

$x^2+y^2=1$ and $(x-1)^2+y^2+(z-2)^2=1$, so $x^2+y^2=(x-1)^2+y^2+(z-2)^2$

solving for $z=2\pm \sqrt{2x-1}$ and $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, so $\gamma (t)=(t, \sqrt{1-t^2}, 2\pm \sqrt{2t-1})$... is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you have the wrong pictures.

We have $$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=1 \\ y^2+z^2=4\end{cases}$$
This is the intersection of 2 cylinders.
It does not involve a circle as in your first picture, nor a sphere as in your second picture.

At point p=(1,0,2) both the x-coordinate and the z-coordinate take a maximum value.
Let us therefore pick $y=t$ as parameter.

Then $\gamma:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R^3$ with
$$\gamma(t)=(\sqrt{1-t^2},\ t,\, \sqrt{4-t^2})$$
does the job.

Alternatively, we can pick polar coordinates for x and y, and subsequently calculate z, so that $\gamma:(-\pi,\pi)\to \mathbb R^3$ with:
$$\gamma(\phi)=(\cos\phi, \sin\phi, \sqrt{4-\sin^2\phi})$$

Comment: Oh, sorry! $B_1(p)=:V$. The sphere is the neighbourhood.

Comment: Then the curve remains the same @ParabolicAlcoholic. It is only the interval $I$ that is affected. Since V is a ball around p, $I$ will be symmetric around $0$.

Comment: But if $V$ is a sphere, then https://www.geogebra.org/m/dexytmmv    how can $\gamma (I)=M\cap V$? Btw. $V:=B_1(p)$.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic, M is a curve and V is not a _sphere_ but a _ball_ (includes the interior). It merely limits the curve M.

Comment: So if $V:=B_1(p)$, $y((-1,1))=M\cap V$?

Comment: If $V$ has radius 1, we still need to find the bounds of $I$ after choosing the curve @ParabolicAlcoholic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104007/discussion-between-parabolicalcoholic-and-klaas-van-aarsen).